# How to query expired case milestone?

Tags: community, salesforcedx, servicecloud

I am trying to query all expired milestones so that I can use them in my flow. I require to send a custom notification to the case owner once a milestone expires. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Get Records elements in flow and filter your records based on your requirement. Please provide more information if you need further help.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is correct approach or not but as i did not get any reference for that, i created flow on case and used decision element where i put condition to filter milestonestatus= open violation and then sending notification to case owner but while saving am getting an error for milestonestatus field “record doesn’t support some standard fields whose values are derived”.